# Ruby add_item for eBay

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ebay-api

I am attempting to write a ruby on rails app that posts an item to eBay. Cody Fauser/Garry Tan have a gem called ebayApi which is built on top of the ebay gem. When I attempt to post an item, I am getting an error back from ebay that says the condition ID is required for this category. I have found a category that does not require the condition, and I can post to that category. Searching through the eBay API documentation, I have found a tag conditionID under the "item" class. However, in the documentation for ebayAPI, there is no such tag. Looking back at the ebay API documentation, there is an older way to specify condition, using lookup_attributes. I have noted that the return xml is coming in API version 745, and Garry Gan's updated of the ruby interface is running version 609. I have tried using the lookup, and seem to get the same error (condition required). I am using the following code to specify the item:

```
@ebay = Ebay::Api.new :auth_token => @seller.ebay_token
item = Ebay::Types::Item.new( :primary_category => Ebay::Types::Category.new(:category_id => @ebayTemplate.categoryID),
:title => @ebayTemplate.name,
:description => @ebayTemplate.description,
:location => @ebayTemplate.location,
:start_price => Money.new((@ebayTemplate.startPrice*100).to_d, @ebayTemplate.currency),
:quantity => 1,
:listing_duration => @ebayTemplate.listingDuration,
:country => @ebayTemplate.country,
:currency => @ebayTemplate.currency,
:payment_methods => ['VisaMC', 'PayPal'],
:paypal_email_address => '********@gmail.com',
:dispatch_time_max => 3,
:lookup_attributes => [Ebay::Types::LookupAttribute.new( :name => "Condition", :value => "New")],
#         :attribute_sets => [
#           Ebay::Types::AttributeSet.new(
#             :attribute_set_id => 2919,
#             :attributes => [
#               Ebay::Types::Attribute.new(
#                 :attribute_id => 10244,
#                 :values => [ Ebay::Types::Val.new(:value_id => 10425) ]
#               )
#              ]
#           )
#         ],
:shipping_details => Ebay::Types::ShippingDetails.new(
:shipping_service_options => [
#              ShippingServiceOptions.new(
#              :shipping_service_priority => 2, # Display priority in the listing
#              :shipping_service => 'UPSNextDay',
#              :shipping_service_cost => Money.new(1000, 'USD'),
#              :shipping_surcharge => Money.new(299, 'USD')
#             ),
Ebay::Types::ShippingServiceOptions.new(
:shipping_service_priority => 1, # Display priority in the listing
:shipping_service => @ebayTemplate.shipSvc,
:shipping_service_cost => Money.new((@ebayTemplate.shipSvcCost*100).to_d, @ebayTemplate.currency),
:shipping_surcharge => Money.new((@ebayTemplate.shipSurcharge*100).to_d, @ebayTemplate.currency)
)
],
:international_shipping_service_options => [
Ebay::Types::InternationalShippingServiceOptions.new(
:shipping_service => 'USPSPriorityMailInternational',
:shipping_service_cost => Money.new((@ebayTemplate.shipSvcCost*100).to_d, @ebayTemplate.currency),
:shipping_service_priority => 2,
:ship_to_location => @ebayTemplate.shipToLocation
)
]

),
:return_policy => Ebay::Types::ReturnPolicy.new (
:description => 'this product for suckers only!',
:returns_accepted_option => 'ReturnsAccepted'
)
#:condition_id => 1000
)

@response = @ebay.add_item(:item => item)
```

As you can see, it is just a mutation of the example given by Cody Fauser. The condition_id at the bottom will bring up an error as there is no such attribute. It seems to me there is no facility for this in the gem since the requirement came into existence after the gem was created. I have not been able to find any other gems to connect with ebay. I have also noticed, there are very little complaints about this even though people are still downloading the gem (10 people downloaded it today). I think there are quite a number of people writing for ebay. Is there a key word I am missing to specify the condition? A work around that people have been using? Another gem I have missed?

Answer (score 0):

There is an existing item_conditions_codes.rb in the gem's type directory and only has two values New and Used. Guess you could add more values in there. However still needs mapping to ID's per the updating (and changed from Attributes) method

You have to modify in the gem library in .. `ruby/1.8/gems/ebayapi-0.12.0/lib/ebay/types/item.rb`
and add the following new lines

```
# added to allow ConditionID to be pushed into XML
numeric_node :condition_id, 'ConditionID', :optional => true
```

then in your ruby ebay code use the following convention

```
:condition_id => 1500,
```

At least that seems to work for me right now.